# Why does a WebKit in fullscreen leaves a border?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I want to learn some [`QtWebKit`](https://github.com/agateau/pyqt-webkit-tutorial/blob/master/tut1/tut1.markdown) (via `PyQT`) and,  taking [an example from a tutorial](https://github.com/agateau/pyqt-webkit-tutorial/blob/master/tut1/tut1.markdown), wanted to display a windows in fullscreen:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        view = QWebView(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(view)

        html = """
            <html><body>
            Hello World!
            </body></html>
            """
        view.setHtml(html)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.showFullScreen()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It works fine, except that the fullscreen windows leaves a gray border:

[image]

When using the same `.showFullScreen()` with `QtGui.QMainWindow` I get a complete coverage of the screen.
I also tried `window.setWindowFlags(PyQt4.QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` but the border is still there (and moreover I do not think that this gray border is not the one  from the decorations - but tried anyway)

Is there a way to have a uniform root window in fullscreen with `QtWebKit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`QLayout.setContentsMargins`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) to remove margins:

```
layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  # <---
layout.addWidget(view)
```